# keySet() usage for <String, List<String>> maps

Tags: java, dictionary

I defined a hashmap as follows:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

And I would like to retrieve the complete list of keys and print them. However, `keySet()` does not work for maps defined as `<String, List<String>>`

```
Set<String, List<String>> keys = hashmap.keySet();
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: it returns a `keySet`, so only `Set<String>` without the `List`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is not the `.keySet()`, but rather the [`.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()):

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> keys = hashmap.entrySet();
```

More info:

- [How to efficiently iterate over each entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)